# CanvasJS - accessing variables - permission denied to access property toString

Tags: javascript, charts

So, I have a form values of which I want to display in a chart. The code is as follows:

```
var chart;

function createChart() {
  console.log($("#kok").val()); // this prints a number
  try {
  chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart", {
    theme: "theme2",
    title: {text:"Kannatus"},
    data: [{
      type:"column",
      dataPoints: [
        {label:"KOK", y:$("#kok").val()}, // the problem is here
        {label:"KESK", y:$("#kesk").val()},
        {label:"SDP", y:$("#sdp").val()},
        {label:"PS", y:$("#ps").val()},
      ]
    }]
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
chart.render();
```

What's wrong here? Should I just use a different library?

Answer (score 1):

Here the type of $("#kok").val() is string. Converting it to Number will help you out.

You can refer http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp